# Dynamically Created SPA using Durandal

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

For our single page app, instead of having a set of defined views and viewmodels that live on the server as .html and .js files, we need to build a system where the views and viewmodels are created in “real-time.”

This will be an intranet app and we want end-users to be able to define what they see and use in the app as they are using the app.  For example, end-user A creates view1, view2, and view3, while end-user B chooses to create view4 and view5, and so forth.  These views are then created in the browser session and saved somehow for the user for the next time they use the app.

They can name these views whatever they want (e.g., dashboard 1, plant view 2, etc.), and then they can select one or more “widgets” to be on each view.  A “widget” would be a contain set of JavaScript/HTML/CSS code, similar to user controls in the web forms world, and would perform its specific function and be able to be draggable and resizable.  Of course, all the widgets that the user has added to each view will be saved for subsequent uses.

So, each time end-user A opens the app, they’ll see their 3 views as tabs across the top (named whatever they named them when the views were configured) and they’ll be able to navigate to the view and see and interact with the widgets they chose on each view.

Our app will sort of be like Trello in which the views can be added, updated, deleted, etc. by the end-user and “widgets” can be added to the views dynamically, moved around, deleted, updated, etc., all in a dynamically created way.

In studying SPAs, the views and viewmodels are developed as actual physical files that live on the production web server and provide the functionality intended to all users.  But, our SPA needs to be more dynamic in terms of what views/pages are available.

Can Durandal be used is this sort of scenario?  If so, any guidance on how to do build such a thing?

Or, is this not possible with Durandal?  If so, what’s a better path for us?

As a last resort, would we need to create some sort of html and JavaScript generator that will output files after the user has selected the configured options?

Or?????

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unless you are letting the users create different Views/Models, this can be handled simply by rendering a View according to different Model data. Then it's just a matter of decided how to update/store the data and how to render the data (i.e. CSS, title, content). Data is generally manipulated via web-services with Durandal. The point is, the *same View/Model* is still used. So you, the developer, creates the architecture and the client provides the data. Otherwise, if the client designs an entirely new widget, it becomes a "Content Management System" - which is hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

durandal is a framework for aiding in creating single page applications (SPAs). SPAs are essentially just a website that feels like a desktop application.

Your only limitations on what you can create are the limitations of the browser.

Anything you can build that runs in a browser.. can be used in durandal.

You can have multiple spas inside of 1 spa.

You can dynamically download css/html/js if you need too.

There are lots of options on how you can structure you application.

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP, and this answer gives no specifics as to how you would actually implement this.  Could you expand on this for us?  How does one get Durandal to dynamically generate the page list and page content for a user without changing the core framework?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you doing this I think.

You can have flexible routing as you define the routes on Durandal start-up so you could use the saved view data to help construct this. But I have a feeling you basically want a shell that other mini applications sit in? Are your views/widgets completely separate to the main application? If so, you might not really need custom routing.

I was working on something similar. I was using iframes to host the applications and the user was able to move them around. I didn't get as far as persisting what the user had laid out though.